# How to upload image on AWS folder in CI

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I have used below code

```
//include the S3 class              
if (!class_exists('S3'))require_once('S3.php');

//AWS access info
if (!defined('awsAccessKey')) define('awsAccessKey', '****************');
if (!defined('awsSecretKey')) define('awsSecretKey', '**************************');
//instantiate the class
$s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);

$s3->putBucket($bucket, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
```

in this where we put Folder Name

Comment: any errors?????

Comment: use putObjectFile

Answer (score 1):

In S3 doesn't exist the concept of folder. What you see as folder in S3 console is just an illusion of folder.

Since each object accept `/` in the key, you can simulate a folder hierarchy (i.e: `images/myphoto.jpg`) but the *filesystem* is still flat.

S3 console simulate for you the folder hierarchy, but this notion is file-related, so you can't use `putBucket`, but `putObject` with a proper key:

From [AWS Doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpPHP.html):

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$bucket = '*** Your Bucket Name ***';
$keyname = 'images/photo.jpg';
// $filepath should be absolute path to a file on disk                      
$filepath = '*** Your File Path ***';

// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = S3Client::factory();

// Upload a file.
$result = $s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'       => $bucket,
    'Key'          => $keyname,
    'SourceFile'   => $filepath,
    'ContentType'  => 'text/plain',
    'ACL'          => 'public-read',
    'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
    'Metadata'     => array(    
        'param1' => 'value 1',
        'param2' => 'value 2'
    )
));

echo $result['ObjectURL'];
```